# PHP - Bucle para buscar elementos dentro de un array

Tags: php, php7, php5

Tengo una variable con un array que tiene este contenido

```
array:9 [▼
          0 => null
          1 => 10.0
          2 => null
          3 => 11
          4 => 10.5
          5 => null
          6 => null
          7 => null
          8 => 12.0
        ]
```

Lo que intento hacer es rellanar los huecos donde hay valores, es decir el elemento [1] del array su valor es 10, pues hasta que encuentre otro elemento con valor, los elementos null que le setee dicho valor.

Es decir el bucle haria desde [2] hasta [3] ambos incluidos como estan a null, los setearia al valor anterior que es "10".

Luego saltaria al elemento[4] y setearia el valor del elemento[5] , [6] i [7] porque estan a null con el valor 10.5

Para ello estoy intentando hacer esto

```
    $bool_ini = false;
    $bool_end = false;
    $valor_inici = null;
    $valor_final = null;
    $pos_ini = null;
    $pos_fin = null;
    $anterior = null;
    $valor_anterior = null;

    $fechas_con_entradas2 = [];
    foreach($fechas_con_entradas as $key => $val) {

        if ($val !== null) {
            if ($bool_ini === true) {
                $pos_end = $key;
                $bool_end = true;
                $valor_final = $pos_end;
                $pos_ini = false;
            }
            else if ($bool_ini === false) {
                $pos_ini = $key;
                $bool_ini = true;
                $valor_inici = $pos_ini;
            }

            if ($bool_end) {
                //cortar
                for ($i=$valor_inici;$i<=$valor_final;$i++) {
                    $fechas_con_entradas[$i] = 'X';
                }
            }
        }
        else if ($bool_ini && $bool_end) {
            $bool_ini = false;
            $bool_end = false;
            $pos_ini = null;
            $pos_fin = null;
        }
        else if ($val === null) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Esto lo que hace es encontrarme los "extremos" me identifica las posiciones [1] y [3] y luego las posiciones  [5] y [8]

Pero lo veo super "rebuscado".

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: ¿Al null que está en array[0] le vas a asignar algún valor, o se queda así?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo, solo necesitas tener una referencia del valor que tiene el elemento anterior, puedes obtenerlo con [índice - 1] o declarando una variable donde se guarde el último valor que no es nulo, prefiero esta última opción:

```
$arr = [
      0 => null,
      1 => 10.0,
      2 => null,
      3 => 11,
      4 => 10.5,
      5 => null,
      6 => null,
      7 => null,
      8 => 12.0
];
// Define una variable para conservar el valor a asignar al encontrar NULL
$anterior = null;
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    // Revisar si el valor actual es nulo
    if($value === null) {
        // Asignar valor anterior
        $arr[$key] = $anterior;
    } else {
        // No es nulo, solo se actualiza variable $anterior
        $anterior = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

El resultado va a ser:

```
[
      0 => null, // El valor con el que inicialices $anterior
      1 => 10.0,
      2 => 10.0,
      3 => 11,
      4 => 10.5,
      5 => 10.5,
      6 => 10.5,
      7 => 10.5,
      8 => 12.0
]
```